# Check ctrl button down at JS onclick function

Tags: javascript, php, html, function

I want to make an check in JavaScript for checking of the CTRL button is clicked. My php:

```
<tr class="clickable" onclick="gotolink('<?= base_url() . invoices/createinvoice/' . $customer->Id; ?>')">
```

my JS code:

```
function gotolink(url) {
        if (HERE THE CHECK FOR THE CTRL BUTTON){
           window.open(url,'_blank');
        }
        else{
            location.href = url;
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to make the check. Could you help me?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

Comment: look for keycode 17

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919459/using-jquery-on-to-watch-for-enter-key-press

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect control+click in Javascript from an onclick div attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190455/how-to-detect-controlclick-in-javascript-from-an-onclick-div-attribute)

Comment: The linked answer is the first result on google by searching "javascript onclick ctrl". Please, search better before opening questions.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function gotolink(url, event) {
  console.log(event.ctrlKey);
  if (event.ctrlKey) {
    window.open(url, '_blank');
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="gotolink('google.com',event)">test</button>
```